# How to revert my .bash_profile changes?

Tags: bash, terminal, .bash-profile

I added the below given simple two commands in my `.bash_profile` -

```
export PS1="___________________    | \w @ \h (\u) \n| => "
export PS2="| => "
```

Then commiting them through the `source .bash_profile`. Now i want to revert back, so i removed the code lines form my `.bash_profile` and activated the changes again using `source .bash_profile` command. But nothing changes after that, so how exactly am i supposed to revert back?

Comment: What do you mean nothing changes?

Comment: Nothing changes because the variables are not set anymore by your `.bash_profile`, so they simply do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply log out and log in again. There is no way to know the state from before your `.bash_profile` set your `PS1` and `PS2` variables.

Most likely they were set by the system `bashrc`, so you could source that again (`source /etc/bash.bashrc`) on Ubuntu.